# How many svchost.exe's are normal?

Tags: windows-10, svchost

I have about 80  [svchost.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svchost.exe)  (79 to be exact) processes running in the background. They are connected to local-service, network-service and system. Most of them are in system. Most of them take 1.5K each, while a few take 11-24K, which is not a lot of memory usage, however: Is it normal to have that many svchost.exe processes running in the background? These are loaded on boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

If you have Windows 10 1709 or higher, each instance represents one active service. I have 73 running on my workstation myself. [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) freeware from Microsoft can be used to identify each service assigned to a svchost.exe instance. .

Comment: Right click on any svchost.exe and select go to services, this will show (highlight) all services running under that particular svchost instance.

Comment: This behavior change was in fact [introduced in Windows 10 1703](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/svchost-service-refactoring). It also is documented, so there is nothing strange or nefarious going on.

Answer (score 0):

Do not trust anyone who tell you that this is normal. Running too many svchost.exe is not normal!!! I got plus 3-5 processe after windows wake up from sleep mode. After couples of wakeups I got windows 10 very slow!!!

After last update I can not decrease svchost.exe with setting `SvcHostSplitThresholdInKB` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`.

From my experience less then 10 svchost.exe is normal.

Comment: …but trust you, who says it’s not normal? There is no need to guess, [this is documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/svchost-service-refactoring). I have 97 `svchost` processes and _this is normal_.

Comment: Did you found any fix for SvcHostSplitThresholdInKB being ignored?